# How to run "nvm" in "oh my zsh"?

Tags: npm, terminal, oh-my-zsh, nvm

In the system there is a `nodejs`, installed through `nvm`. The command is not running `npm`.
Console is `Oh my zsh`

Comment: use oh-my-zsh plugins [`zsh-nvm`](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm)

Answer (score 192):

**Switching from Bash to Oh-My-Zsh**

If you already have `nvm` installed and you're switching from `bash` to `oh-my-zsh` you can simply open up your `.zshrc` file and add the `nvm` plugin that is included with `oh-my-zsh`:

1. Open your zsh config file`.zshrc` in nano with this command: `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Scroll down to where it shows `plugins=(git)` and add `nvm` inside the parentheses to make it show as `plugins=(git nvm)` (separate plugins with spaces)
3. Press `control` + `O` (on macOS), then `enter`, to save, then press `control` + `X` to exit
4. Then open a new terminal window/tab and enter `nvm ls` to confirm it works. Note that you must open a new window/tab for your shell to use the newly updated `.zshrc` config (or enter `source ~/.zshrc`, etc.)

Source: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/nvm

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer. I think the only way to improve this answer is: Adding a Header (Moved from Bash to zsh) and add some linebreaks

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @duichwer. I just made those edits.

Comment: This is the correct and proper answer, please ignore the others lol.

Comment: you are a savior

Comment: we ran into this issue because we had oh-my-zsh on top of basic zsh. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What is when a new terminal tab is opened and `nvm ls` doesn't work?

Comment: @newguy - It's possible the file zsh config file wasn't saved, or your new terminal tab didn't load the new zsh config file. Try opening the `.zshrc` file again and check that your changes were saved. And then try running `source ~/.zshrc` or run `exec zsh` to have your shell run the latest zsh config

Answer (score 186):

You can use [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm) or enable it yourself by adding following lines to your ~/.zshrc

```
 export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

**Extra:**

For faster shell initialization, I use `lazynvm` which only loads node when needed

```
lazynvm() {
  unset -f nvm node npm
  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
}

nvm() {
  lazynvm 
  nvm $@
}

node() {
  lazynvm
  node $@
}

npm() {
  lazynvm
  npm $@
}
```

Reference: [Lazy load nvm for faster shell start](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/4tg5jg/lazy_load_nvm_for_faster_shell_start/)

Comment: If anyone is using Vim for development, the lazy loading causes autocompletion using tsserver to fail because tsserver won't be found in PATH. Best to just use eager loading IMHO.

Comment: If I add this to ~/.zshrc, I get "command not found" when running nvm? How do I use this?

Comment: make sure your .zshrc has been loaded: you can type "lazy" and press Tab to see if the ZSH auto-completion shows you lazynvm. if not, check your shell config or ZSH config to make sure it's loading the `.zshrc`

Comment: If using oh-my-zsh, the nvm plugin already has lazy loading implemented, so skip to the next answer.

Comment: For anyone wondering `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]` => `-s FILE - True if the FILE exists and has nonzero size`

Answer (score 42):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Install or update nvm

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Run the following commands in your terminal to add to your ~/.zshrc

```
echo 'export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm' >> ~/.zshrc
echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Load in the current shell environment

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Check the nvm version

```
nvm -v
```

Answer (score 21):

use homebrew to install nvm

1. `brew install nvm`
2. edit your system configuration

```
    vim ~/.zshrc     # or  vim ~/.bashrc
    export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
```

esc > :wq
save file

3. reload the configuration
   `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`
4. view nvm version

```
$ nvm --version
# 0.36.0
```

enjoy it.

Comment: `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` was the missing piece for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. Glad I tried this before doing any reinstallation.

Comment: wth is :wq ????

Answer (score 17):

A much easier solution is to use the [nvm plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/nvm) that is shipped by default:

> It also automatically sources nvm, so you don't need to do it manually
>   in your .zshrc

1. `git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git ~/.nvm`
2. `cd ~/.nvm && git checkout v0.35.1` (current latest [release](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases))
3. Add `nvm` to your `~/.zshrc`.  Ex: `plugins=(... nvm)`

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I discovered that there is a nvm plug-in shipping with oh-my-zsh (that's different from lukechilds plugin). After short inspection, I think it adds the necessary modifications to `.zshrc` when loading, so simply adding `nvm` to the plugins list in `.zshrc` should work as well (and it does for me).

I did not find any more details on that default nvm plugin via google so I don't know whether this is the "go-to" solution.

Comment: As of this writing, adding `nvm` as a plugin did not work for me on a Mac (OS should not be a factor, though). I still get `zsh: command not found: nvm`. I'll try adding manually.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. May I know what you mean by `adding manually`?

Comment: To get [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm) working, I had to find the section in the README [how to install plugin](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm#as-an-oh-my-zsh-custom-plugin). Steps involved: `git clone https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-nvm` and I had to edit the `~/.zshrc` file and to add the plugin `plugins=( git zsh-nvm )`. Loaded new terminal and `nvm list` finally worked.

Answer (score 8):

With Linux (Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, 22.10 and 23.04)

With your favorite editor, you edit  `~/.zshrc`

```
nano or vi ~/.zshrc
```

At the end of the file, you add :

```
# NVM
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

And then you run :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this code to .zshrc on your user directory

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Then run this code on your terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest using [christophemarois' approach to lazy loading nvm (node, npm and global packages)](https://gist.github.com/fl0w/07ce79bd44788f647deab307c94d6922#gistcomment-2650045) in order to avoid slow shell starting times:

```
# Add every binary that requires nvm, npm or node to run to an array of node globals
NODE_GLOBALS=(`find ~/.nvm/versions/node -maxdepth 3 -type l -wholename '*/bin/*' | xargs -n1 basename | sort | uniq`)
NODE_GLOBALS+=("node")
NODE_GLOBALS+=("nvm")

# Lazy-loading nvm + npm on node globals call
load_nvm () {
  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  [ -s "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" ] && . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
}

# Making node global trigger the lazy loading
for cmd in "${NODE_GLOBALS[@]}"; do
  eval "${cmd}(){ unset -f ${NODE_GLOBALS}; load_nvm; ${cmd} \$@ }"
done
```