# Unable to add 'nvm' plugin to zsh through oh my zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have recently just started using wsl and zsh for dev purposes and I have tried to add the nvm through as a plugin in zsh through the ~/.zshrc file. I've added, saved and reloaded the terminal several times and tries the nvm command and it comes out with the 'zsh: command not found: nvm' error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `source ~/.zshrc` doesn't work, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009776/how-to-run-nvm-in-oh-my-zsh/51696357).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add nvm's loading script to `~/.zshrc`. This instruction can be found on the [readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#git-install).

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

You can test with:

```
which node
```

Hope this works :)